# Assigning lists to a series by index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove a string from a list, inside a dataframe. For that, I will use a list of indexes that match certain criteria. I'm using a for loop and a list comprehension to do so:

```
to_remove = ['International']

for i in [267, 337, 619, 632, 681, 745, 934, 1341, 1379, 2059]:
    train.loc[i, 'tags'] = [x for x in train['tags'][i] if x not in to_remove]
```

Getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

working with a serie full of lists with different lenght. For example:

```
Tag
['Veggie', 'Internacional']
['Veggie', 'Peruvian', 'Asian', 'Latin']
['Veggie', 'Fast food', 'Latin', 'Internacional']
['Veggie']
```

**Expected output:**

```
 Tag
 ['Veggie']
 ['Veggie', 'Peruvian', 'Asian', 'Latin']
 ['Veggie', 'Fast food', 'Latin']
 ['Veggie']
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample data ?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you can using

```
[[y for y in x if y not in to_remove ] for x in df.Tag ]
Out[339]: 
[['Veggie'],
 ['Veggie', 'Peruvian', 'Asian', 'Latin'],
 ['Veggie', 'Fast food', 'Latin'],
 ['Veggie']]
```